# "With probabilty $1$" (almost surely) for countable sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, a discrete-time stochastic process with state space $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $S$ finite.

In my lecture notes there is written

"$X_t \geq f(X_{t-1})$ with probability $1$"

and sometimes there is written

"$X_t \geq f(X_{t-1})$"

So am I right in assuming that for discrete state spaces (finite or countably infinite), these two statements are equivalent, meaning that for every possible outcome we have that this property holds?

The reason why one distinguishes between these two cases is only the continuous state space. So if $S =[0,1]$, say, then the first statement means that $X_t < f(X_{t-1})$ is possible but happens only with probability 0, whereas the second statement means that for every possible outcome we have that $X_t \geq f(X_{t-1})$.

And of course a hidden question: If we have a discrete state space, then an event with probability 0 will never happen and hence can be excluded from the state space?

Is this true?

In general: If we write $X \geq Y$ for random variables, does this mean that this is valid for every possible outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, or are there several meanings of this "notation"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This confuses the state space and the probability space. Define $X$ on the probability space $\Omega=[0,1]$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure by $X(\omega)=0$ if $\omega$ is irrational and $X(\omega)=1$ if $\omega$ is rational. Then $X=0$ almost surely and the state space of $X$ is the finite set $S=\{0,1\}$ but $X=0$ is wrong since $X(.5)\ne0$.

Comment: I think what you hypothesize is true but it is always more convenient for us to say that something happens a.s. since we do not want to be too careful about the "state space". $X\geq Y$ usually means $\forall \omega$ the inequality holds.

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out, I was sure I was messing something up. So the above is correct if I replace "state space discrete" by "probability space discrete". Whether the state space is discrete or not does not play any role for having eliminated the "probabilty 0 "-case?